# AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock (*) failed in docker

Tags: docker, apache2, php-7.0

Hello first time dockerize my project.

Below are my files:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apache2/Dockerfile
    container_name: markitplace-php
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./www/html:/var/www/html
      - ./apache2/configs:/etc/apache2/sites-available
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - php
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: markitplace
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin0101
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./www/html/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db:
```

apache2/Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    a2enmod rewrite && \
    a2dissite 000-default.conf

RUN wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb

RUN dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb
# Install FastCGI module
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-fastcgi

# Enable FastCGI module
RUN a2enmod fastcgi


RUN a2enmod actions
COPY apache2/configs/php7-fcgi.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/php7-fcgi.conf
RUN a2enconf php7-fcgi  
RUN a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif  
    

COPY apache2/configs/docker.markitplace.local.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/docker.markitplace.local.conf
RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2ensite docker.markitplace.local.conf


WORKDIR /var/www/html
#COPY html/ /var/www/html/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

apache2/configs/docker.markitplace.local.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName docker.markitplace.local
  ServerAlias www.docker.markitplace.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://php:9000"
    </FilesMatch>

  <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

ServerName docker.markitplace.local
```

apache2/configs/php7-fcgi.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
   AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
   Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi
   Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
   FastCGIExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /var/run/php-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0.33-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache bash mysql-client msmtp perl wget procps shadow libzip libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp freetype icu

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-essentials \
    icu-dev icu-libs zlib-dev g++ make automake autoconf libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev libwebp-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    apk del build-essentials && rm -rf /usr/src/php*

RUN apk --no-cache add git curl zlib-dev libpng-dev

RUN echo 'listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock\n' > /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-socket.conf
# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    composer self-update
RUN command -v composer

RUN php -v
RUN composer --version
#RUN node -v
#RUN npm -v
#
# Configure PHP
#COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Add application
#COPY www/html /var/www/html

# Give permissions

# RUN composer install
COPY ./www/html/ /var/www/html/

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/ && chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/ && chmod -R 777 storage && chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage
RUN php artisan config:clear
#RUN composer dump-autoload
RUN composer install
RUN composer dump-autoload

# Expose port 9000 and start PHP-FPM server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Can anyone please help me out what I am doing wrong. When access localhost:8000 below error is showing up in the logs of apache2

```
AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS

(2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock (*) failed
```